# Can i develop a outlook 2007 addin in vs 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, outlook-addin

I want to create a add in for outlook 2007. Can i use visual studio 2013 for that.
pls help. same question answer give more confusions.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. I'd recommend using the lowest version of interop files (PIAs) to avoid exceptions in the code at runtime when trying to use absent members.

> If your customer base uses the 2007 Microsoft Office system, you can use Visual Studio 2013 to develop solutions that work in all three versions of Office. In this scenario, the solution will run without errors in the 2007 Microsoft Office system only if the solution doesn’t use features that are new in later versions of Office. Microsoft Office applications can also run solutions that were created by using a previous version of Visual Studio.

Read more about that in the [Running Solutions in Different Versions of Microsoft Office](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772080(v=vs.120).aspx) article.